# How to get this side by side?

Tags: tabbing

I have the following code:

```
$ax = b \Leftrightarrow$
```

and

```
\begin{tabbing}
    $a_{11}x_1 + $ \= $a_{12}x_2+\dots +$ \= $a_{1n}x_n$ \= $= b_1$\\
    \> $a_{22}x_2 + \dots +$ \> $a_{2n}x_n$ \> $= b_2$\\
    \> $\ddots$ \> $\vdots$ \> $\vdots$\\
    \> \> $a_{nn}x_n$ \> $= b_n,$
\end{tabbing}
```

But how can I get, that these two parts are side by side?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know the environments `align` and `array`? Maybe you should read the mathmode.

Comment: And a link to [math-mode](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode) as suggested my @MarcoDaniel Just to get you on the right track ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple `array` can be used instead of `tabbing`, which also centers itself vertically with the math axis:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mcr}{\multicolumn{1}{r}}

\begin{document}

\[
  AX = B
  \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}% No intercolumn space in array
  \begin{array}{rccl}
    a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2 & {}+ \cdots + a_{1n}x_n & {}={}  & b_1 \\
                a_{22}x_2 & {}+ \cdots + a_{2n}x_n & {}={}  & b_2 \\[\jot]
                   \ddots &      \mcr{\vdots\quad} & \vdots &     \\[\jot]
                          &        \mcr{a_{nn}x_n} & {}={}  & b_n,
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Werner, just in case you are interested, take a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7303/27635

Comment: Thanks! This is great. I was waiting for a review queue to be established, but in the meantime it's probably best to go ahead and fix what we can.

Answer (score 4):

I would follow the suggestions in the above comments, but just in case you don't want to change your code, you can exploit `minipage`. Inserting a `tabbing` inside it causes the `minipage` to use the width of the `tabbing`, as egreg suggested in his comments.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$ax = b \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad$
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{tabbing}
    $a_{11}x_1 + $ \= $a_{12}x_2+\dots +$ \= $a_{1n}x_n$ \= $= b_1$\\
    \> $a_{22}x_2 + \dots +$ \> $a_{2n}x_n$ \> $= b_2$\\
    \> $\ddots$ \> $\vdots$ \> $\vdots$\\
    \> \> $a_{nn}x_n$ \> $= b_n,$
\end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

The same result can be achieved using the `varwidth` environment from the same package.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}

$ax = b \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad$
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\begin{tabbing}
    $a_{11}x_1 + $ \= $a_{12}x_2+\dots +$ \= $a_{1n}x_n$ \= $= b_1$\\
    \> $a_{22}x_2 + \dots +$ \> $a_{2n}x_n$ \> $= b_2$\\
    \> $\ddots$ \> $\vdots$ \> $\vdots$\\
    \> \> $a_{nn}x_n$ \> $= b_n,$
\end{tabbing}
\end{varwidth}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There's no need of `varwidth`; try `\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}` instead and you'll get the same result. A `minipage` that only contains a `tabbing` uses the width of the `tabbing` (unless it's wider than the stated `minipage` width). Also the first `varwidth` you use is redundant.

Comment: @egreg Is this true for the first `varwidth`?

Comment: Why would you need it?

Comment: @egreg Stupid me, you're right...